# Effective way to process arrays of big integers with GMP

Tags: arrays, simd, biginteger, gmp

I'm primary considering processing of arrays of 128 - 512 bits integers. If use GMP, what is most effective way, maybe with low level mpn_XXX functions?

Say, I want an addition function like this:

```
void add_arrays(size_t n, mpz_t *result, mpz_t *restrict a, mpz_t *restrict b)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    mpz_add(result[i], a[i], b[i]);
}
```

The function is single threaded (no loop OpenMP-ing). SIMD utilization is *extremely* desirable. CPU: x86_64 (AVX2/AVX512).

Please notice, since we are processing arrays, properly organized SIMD code (not GMP, but custom) may outperform scalar one based on ADC instruction.

Comment: Can you store your data interleaved, so one vector can hold one element from each input number, rather than both elements from half as many numbers?  With 128-bit integers, only need two 64-bit halves, so you don't need an add with carry-in *and* carry-out, so there might possibly be something to gain here even if you have to shuffle to get low halves in one vector, high halves in another vector, from two interleaved inputs.  (e.g. 2x `vshufps` or `vpunpckldqq` / `vpunpckhqdq` 2-input shuffles that operate within 128-bit lanes.)   `vpaddq` and `carry = a<(a+b)` with AVX-512 `vpcmpuq`.

Comment: Yes I do. I already did it for myself by the way you described. Thx! Since GMP is a widely used lib, I'm interesting about any possibility to use it effectively for processing arrays of big ints. I think GMP is not good for that (by design), but maybe some tricks exist?

Comment: Yes, like I commented on your previous question, ([SIMD (AVX2, AVX512) big integer library](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/132701479)), state-of-the-art bigint stuff leaves some spare bits in each limb so you can use SIMD without having to propagate carry every operation, at least not all the way.  But it means users of the bigint routines need to be aware of how long they can defer renormalization, and it uses a different representation, so it's not a drop-in replacement for GMP.

Comment: Also yes, GMP is designed for quite large bigints, not for arrays of fixed-size integer only a couple times the size of a register.  Call/return overhead would be high for that, vs. a good loop that does 4x load + add + 3x adc + 4x store.  Out-of-order exec can overlap the short add/adc dep chains.  It's hard (slow) to implement the middle steps (adc with carry-in and carry-out) with SIMD, so IDK if there's anything to gain even with pre-interleaved data with AVX-512.  Almost certainly not with AVX2 (only 4 qword elements per vector, only signed compares.)

Comment: Thx for your answers! Spare bits in each limb are best with AVX512IFMA, I think, since it is already non-unsual 52-bit wide limb. AVX2 pays two additional XOR instructions to make signed CMP applicable to unsigned domain.

Comment: And AVX512 compare is a bottleneck, since it consumes only port5 due to mask-way, so each second compare needs to be replaced with sub and further blend on ports0,1 for better throughput, maybe.

Comment: How would SUB/BLEND work?  The unsigned compare result is in the carry-out, not the MSB.  (Or for signed, in OF != SF).  Current Intel CPUs only have two SIMD execution ports that can handle 512-bit instructions, and `vpcmpuq` is less than 1/2 of the total ALU instructions you'd run for this.  (Note that no ZMM instructions can run on port 1, only XMM/YMM.  At least for now; perhaps in future CPUs years from now, but if so they'll also have better compare throughput.)

Comment: AVX-512IFMA is not the only reason for leaving spare bits in each limb.  Read Mysticial's answer re: using `vmulpd` to take advantage of the mantissa multipliers for exact integer math.  And also I already pointed out another very major benefit: not having to propagate carry all the way through the limbs when adding, like in this case.  (Maybe more significant for more limbs per number, but still a big deal if you can do 16 additions of vectors of 500-bit numbers with just `vpaddq`, and propagate carry by shifting + shuffling to pull the high bits down to the bottom, instead of having to vpcmp

Comment: My thought was such: Ports 0,1 are both 256-bit, but combined to process 512-bit instruction (operating with ZMM). Port5 is 512-bit and only port that handles mask returning instructions like CMP. Ports 0,1 combined can process at the same time SUB/BLEND pair to get carry-out in register form (0/-1). During 2 cycles there are executed 2 CMP on port5 and 1 SUB/BLEND pair on port0,1 , resulting throughput increasing on 50%.

Comment: But it's sort of "theoretical" estimation. You are right about other instructions in the flow which would be else executed on port0,1.

Comment: Unsigned a > b via SUB/BLEND: 
1. VPSUBQ sign, a, b; 
2. VBLENDVPD carry, 0, -1, sign
(Instead VBLENDVPD SAR may be used)
... and I forgot that AVX512 has no variable BLEND version (which uses sign bit as selector).

Comment: Ok yeah, you're assuming the operands to subtraction are within 2^63-1 of each other, not the full range of unsigned 2^64-1. Like I said, you're assuming the MSB of the sub is the same as carry/borrow.  It's not, carry-out it the 65th bit.  For 8-bit, consider `0xFF - 1 == 0xFE`.  That leaves the MSB set, but with borrow=0.  `0x80 - 1 = 0x7F` is the largest difference where your method reliably works, when the absolute difference is signed positive, and would fit in int8_t not just uint8_t.

Comment: No, I'm assuming full range 0..2^64-1 for the limb. Consider unsigned sum s = a + b. Carry out condition: s < a (or b) = s - a (or b) < 0. Then SUB s, a gives sign bit indicating carry presence. Then SAR >> 63 (or BLEND) gives carry in register form (0/-1 - all bits are zeros or ones), which then is added to next limb via SUB (SUB -1 == ADD 1).

Comment: I meant you're *accidentally* assuming that.  I just gave you a counterexample where the MSB of a SUB isn't the unsigned `s < a` result.  Work through it yourself for `0xFE + 1 = 0xFF`, then `0xFF < 1` by `0xFF - 1 = 0xFE`.  (Or make it 64-bit if you want.)  That's why scalar `jb` looks at CF, not SF, because they're not the same.

Comment: Yes, thx! Obvious thing. My brain is a bit rusted on bit level ;)

Comment: We may wrap 0x80 boundary, so an addition checking is required with SUB way.

Comment: I think it would cost so many extra instructions that's it's not worth it vs. XOR/XOR/VPCMPGTQ even if you don't have AVX-512 available for VPCMPUQ.  Or of course range-limit your limbs so the inputs all have some zeros at the top, letting you get carry-out from addition with just a `vpsraq y, y, 62` + `vpermq` or something.  If you leave 2 spare bits in a normalized number, that should be enough for one carry-propagation step every addition to keep it from accumulating and losing any.  (Or AVX-512 `valignq` to left-shift across 128-bit boundaries, with masking to shift in a 0)

Comment: Yep, carry-out condition of s = a + b in unsigned domain without using CMP might look like this: carry = ((a & b) | (~s & (a ^ b))) SAR 63, which is too long to be useful.